# Debezium server fffset file storage claim or cleanup

Tags: debezium, debezium-engine, debezium-server

So, for non-kafka deployment, we specify offset storage file with `debezium.source.offset.storage.file.filename` as per [documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/operations/debezium-server.html#debezium-source-configuration-properties), how does the storage is reclaimed or cleanup happens?

I am planning to have k8s deployment with mounted volume as,

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: debezium-gke
  labels:
    name: debezium
spec:
  serviceName: debezium
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: debezium
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: debezium
          image: debezium_server:1.10
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          volumeMounts:
            - name: debezium-config-volume
              mountPath: /debezium/conf
            - name: debezium-data-volume
              mountPath: /debezium/data
      volumes:
        - name: debezium-config-volume
          configMap:
            name: debezium
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: debezium-data-volume
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10G
```

But wondering if the disk spaces gets filled in if storage reclaim doesn't happen!

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "if storage get's filled"? Debezium will keep on that mounted volume a single file named `offsets.dat`. That's it. That file should not be removed if you want Debezium to not lose data.

Comment: @TudorPlugaru ya, i hear you that it writes into that file in volume mounted, but over the time, file gets bigger and bigger that is larger than size of volume! how does it handle that?

Comment: I assume you can just trim the file. From my knowledge, Debezium only needs the last commited offset when it's starting. Old offsets are not used.

Comment: @TudorPlugaru oh okay! have you done yourself or see someone doing? i can give a try, but need to figure out how to trim dat file, like cron or something else